# Use Row_Number() in case statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Left Joined 2 table Table A and Table B and the output is below which is correct

```
select a.id,b.OS_ID from TableA left join TableB
on a.id=b.id
```

What I want to achieve is replacing NULL with 51 and 52.

If I run this

```
Declare @OSID int
set @OSID = (select max(os_ID) from OS_Master)
```

It will give me output as 50, Then I want to increment by 1 for the next entry and replace the NULL value

ID  OS_ID
1   1
1   14
1   NULL
1   NULL

If I do this:

```
Declare @OSID int
set @OSID = (select max(os_ID) from OS_Master)
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by os_ID) + @OSID from OS_Master
```

It works fine, ROW_NUMBER() starts from 51, But If I incorporate it with the join like

```
select a.ID,case when b.OS_ID is null then (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b.os_ID) + @OSID ) 
else b.OS_ID END    from TABLEA a
left JOIN TABLEB  b
on a.ID=b.ID
```

It shows 51 for both the NULL records, How to get 51,52 ans so on in my query

Comment: Please clarify the contents of both tables A and B.

Comment: You mention about `output`, `NULL` but you didn't show us how the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.id,
       coalesce(b.OS_ID, om.max_os_id + row_number() over (partition by b.os_id)) as os_id
from TableA left join
     TableB
     on a.id = b.id cross join
     (select max(os_ID)  as max_os_id from OS_Master) om;
```

This increments the value based on the maximum value, using `row_number()`.